# Patch request is forever stuck on pending

Tags: node.js, reactjs, http, fetch, http-post

This is my code on the front end

```
fetch('http://localhost:5001/api/data', {
                method: 'PATCH',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    "formulaString": formula,
                    "index": props.id
                })
```

And just to test things; my backend code is kept simple as follows

```
app.patch('/api/data', (req, res) => { console.log(req.body) }
```

On triggering the event that leads to the request on the front end; My network has two items :

1. A preflight with status 204
2. The actual fetch req that is just stuck on the pending status forever

My backend just logs `Undefined` which I assume is from the preflight. Not sure on how I should be tackling this; Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: your code works fine for me. maybe you are not sending any response from the server, so  the request is on pending..

Answer (score 1):

Your server not sending any response.

```
app.patch('/api/data', (req, res) => { console.log(req.body); }
```

Instead

```
app.patch('/api/data', (req, res) => { 
 console.log(req.body);
 res.send("working fine") 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! But the issue is despite that the `console.log(req.body);` just logs `undefined`

Comment: it works fine for me & it logs the input which i send in the frontend..

Comment: That's weird as the payload on the network tab looks as intended too. Not sure why it would not work on the backend.

Comment: do you using nodemon or just running on node ?  if you are running on node, just kill the server & rerun

Comment: Yeah, using nodemon. Probably something wrong on my local system as any http req id not showing the body in this app